# Download only recently modified files with wget over FTP

Tags: ftp, wget, timestamps

When fetching recursively with `wget` from an FTP server, how can I download only files modified after a given date?

The use case is that I need to sync with several servers nightly, but I only need the data from a couple days back. The `--mirror` flag would suffice, except that syncing the rest of the data (even just once) would take forever.

Answer (score 2):

`wget` can mirror once and then after this only get later items with the `--timestamp` flag. I'd suggest reading the `info` page for it, which has a good explanation, and checking if this gives you the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: In fact, `--mirror` implies `--timestamping`.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not supported by wget unless you have already synced once, whether through wget or not (in which case, see `--timestamp`).

Here are some workarounds you could try:

- If files contain dates in the name or path, and not just on the file modification time, you may be able to use regexes/directories to exclude old files.
- Use something other than `wget`. This seems like a good candidate for a dedicated script. You can still use wget for a file at a time. You might also check out wpull, which I haven't used but I understand is similar to wget with scripting to determine whether to download pages.
- If you have an HTTP download option in addition to FTP, you may be able to send custom HTTP cache directive headers which only download the file if it's modified after a certain date.